# Android auto moving images

Tags: android, image

What is the best options for auto moving a images in android.
(Number of images and image title are randomized generating.)

```
               ____________ 
<- direction   | screen    |
```

image1<--10px-->image2<--10px-->image3<--10px-->etc..

Something like ordinary gallery in android, but it have to be automatic.

Comment: creating multiple images with different positions and play them using `animation-list` ?

Comment: You mean like a Slider?

Comment: No like slider. I'll try View Animation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by animation.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
`<translate`
   `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
   `android:duration = "4000"`
   `android:fromXDelta="100%p"`
   `android:toXDelta="-100%p"`
   `/>`